# How to load ePub from internal storage in ionic4?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic4, hybrid-mobile-app, epub.js

I have to load epub from internal storage device in ionic4. I have wasted my time not get any solution.

When I load epub from assets, its load properly, but when i am loading epub from ineternal storage device, can't load without error. Plz give me solution.

```
   this.book = ePub("assets/temp1.epub");    
   this.rendition = this.book.renderTo("area", {
    spread: "always"
  });
 this.rendition.display();
```

its displays properly

```
     const path = this.file.externalRootDirectory + 'ePub/temp1.epub';   
this.book = await ePub(path);   
      
      this.rendition = this.book.renderTo("area", {
        spread: "always"
      });
this.rendition.display();
```

its can't displays

Answer (score 0):

You can get this using sdcard file as ArrayBuffer as parameter of ePub()

```
 this.file.readAsArrayBuffer(this.file.externalRootDirectory + '/appname/'+ '/', filename).then(arrayBuffer => {
        var book = ePub(arrayBuffer);
        var rendition = book.renderTo("area", { method: "default", width: "100%", height: "100%" });
      }).catch(err => { });
```